# How can I translate "un ámbito cerrado" into English?

Tags: traducción, poesía

Here's [a poem](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626144209/http://www.migato.com:80/conocele/el-gato-en-la-cultura/a-un-gato-de-borges) by Borges that I tried to translate into English:

### A Un Gato

> No son más silenciosos los espejos
> ni más furtiva el alba aventurera;
> eres, bajo la luna, esa pantera
> que nos es dado divisar de lejos.
> Por obra indescifrable de un decreto
> divino, te buscamos vanamente;
> más remoto que el Ganges y el poniente,
> tuya es la soledad, tuyo el secreto.
> Tu lomo condesciende a la morosa
> caricia de mi mano. Has admitido,
> desde esa eternidad que ya es olvido,
> el amor de la mano recelosa.
> En otro tiempo estás. Eres el dueño
> de un ámbito cerrado como un sueño.
> —Jorge Luis Borges

I'm not thoroughly satisfied with my attempt:

### Of A Cat

> None are more silent mirrors
> nor more furtive venturing dawn;
> under the moon, you are that panther
> which we are given to spy from afar.
> By indecipherable work of decree
> divine, we search for you in vain;
> more remote than the Ganges and the west wind,
> yours is the solitude, yours the secret.
> Your back condescends to the lingering
> caress of my hand. You have admitted,
> from that eternity that already is forgotten,
> the love of the distrustful hand.
> You exist in another time. You are the landlord
> of a closed circle like a dream.

In particular, the last two lines are difficult for me to understand in Spanish, let alone render in English.  How should I understand "un ámbito cerrado"?

---

I've seen a few other English renderings online:

- [You preside over a world as closed-off to us as a dream.](https://tomclarkblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/jorge-luis-borges-un-gato-to-cat.html)
- [You are the lord of a private land, like a dream.](https://intrepiddreamer.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/a-un-gato-to-a-cat/)

And of course [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) suggests:

- You are the master in a closed environment like a dream.

Comment: Side comment: reading the title and the poem, a more adequate translation for the former would be _To a Cat_ (not _of_ a cat)

Comment: The renderings you quoted work much better than what you proposed. For example, "landlord" is all wrong, because there's no renting going on; "cerrado como" isn't "closed like" here, but rather, "as closed as" or "as closed off as."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we shouldn't be translating poetry.  If you're not sure what a certain phrase *means*, that's different, and we can try to help with that.

Comment: A un gato is **To a cat**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ámbito as defined by the [Real Academia Española](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=%C3%A1mbito):

> ámbito.
>
> (Del lat. ambĭtus).
>
> 1. m. Contorno o perímetro de un espacio o lugar.
> 2. m. Espacio comprendido dentro de límites determinados.
> 3. m. Espacio ideal configurado por las cuestiones y los problemas de una o varias actividades o disciplinas relacionadas entre sí. Esto
>    pertenece al ámbito de la psicología, no al de la sociología.

Which means that it can be an environment a perimeter or a context. But be aware that in the case of the poem IMHO and interpretation it doesn't represent a place in space, but rather an attitude and a time, something rather foreign. So the last two verses I would translate them as follows:

> En otro tiempo estás. Eres el dueño
> de un ámbito cerrado como un sueño.

Into:

> You exist in another time.You are the owner
>
> of a closed circle like a dream.

or

> You exist in another time. You are the owner
>
> of a closed world like a dream.

Answer (score 4):

Literally, *ámbito* can be translated as *context*.

The cat owns its own world, inaccessible like a dream. Those English renderings seem quite correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

The translation I would have rendered for "ámbito cerrado" is a "closed system." But your "closed circle" is more than adequate, and actually more poetic.

Comment: The tricky thing about translating poetry is to make the result match some of the "feel" of the source, which isn't always possible.  (Thanks for the affirmation. ;-)